# Glass and gloss reflections in evee

Tags: eevee-render-engine, reflection

Anyone know how to do reflections on large flat glass or glossy planar objects (like building windows) in eevee?  This was very simple to do with Blender 2.7's Internal Render Engine. I want that, in broad daylight, in a city, buildings that surround a particular building be reflected in its windows. 2.7's Internal Render Engine could do it practically out of the box. Can eevee do it? Thanks

Comment: Hello and welcome :). *Screen Space Reflections* are disabled in Eevee by default to make it fast. You can enable them, then go *File > Defaults > Save Startup file* and they'll stay enabled :).

Comment: I'm voting to close this post, because *"fix eevee to handle reflections like the old internal render engine did"* is not a question. You can improve the post by adding a question with a question mark. [By the way, you can just continue using 2.79.]

Comment: @Leander - Thanks, I edited it into a question.

Comment: @JachymMichal - Thanks, but even with Screen Space Reflections enabled, distant reflections (like I describe) just don't work.